# React Native How to Access Child's Ref from Parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to access child component's ref from parent component but I'm failing. I have tab navigation and from tab nav I want to open a bottom sheet so I need to reach bottom sheet's ref from Tab Navigation. This is my code =>

```
const addPostSheet = React.forwardRef((_, ref) => {
    
    const sheetRef = ref

    const renderContent = () => {
        <View style={styles.panel}>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.panelButton}>
                <Text style={styles.panelButtonTitle}>Take Photo</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.panelButton}>
                <Text style={styles.panelButtonTitle}>Choose From Library</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.panelButton} onPress={sheetRef.current.snapTo(1)}>
                <Text style={styles.panelButtonTitle}>Cancel</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    }
    const fall = new Animated.Value(1)
    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <BottomSheet 
                ref={sheetRef}
                snapPoints={[330, 0]}
                renderContent={renderContent}
                initialSnap={1}
                enabledGestureInteraction={true}
                enabledBottomInitialAnimation={true}
                callbackNode={fall}
            />
        </View>
    )
}) 
    


const BottomTabNavigator = () => {
 
    const sheetRef = useRef(null)

    return (
        <Tab.Navigator
            screenOptions={({route}) => ({
                tabBarIcon: ({focused, color, size}) => {
                    let iconName
                    if (route.name === "home"){
                        iconName = focused ? 'ios-home' : 'ios-home-outline'
                        color = 'black'
                        size = 32
                    } else if (route.name === "add"){
                        iconName = focused ? 'add-circle-sharp' : 'add-circle-outline'
                        color = 'orange'
                        size = 32
                    } else if (route.name === "search"){
                        iconName = focused ? 'search' : 'search-outline'
                        color = 'black'
                        size = 32
                    }

                    return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={size} color={color}/>
                },
            })}
            initialRouteName="home"
            tabBarOptions={{
                showLabel: false
            }}
        >
            <Tab.Screen name="home" component={DrawerNavigator}/>
            <Tab.Screen name="add" component={addPostSheet} listeners={({navigation}) => ({
                tabPress: event => {
                    sheetRef.current.snapTo(0)
                }
            })} />
            <Tab.Screen name="search" component={SearchStack}/>
        </Tab.Navigator>
    )
}
```

However, I got `Cannot read property "snapTo" of null` error, I think parent's ref stays `null` all the time. So how can I effect `BottomSheet` from Tab Navigation?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have solved your problem yet.

Before your app executes sheetRef.current.snapTo(0), you want to store the refs in a local variable. For example, you write

const storedRef = sheetRef.current;

Then, right before the following code executes

```
        tabPress: event => {
            sheetRef.current.snapTo(0)
```

you run the following line

```
sheetRef.current = storedRef;
```

This directs sheetRef to use the correct refs.

Doing this allowed me to solve a problem that I had that is similar to yours.